# Minimum Profit Editor Autocomplete

Tags: c++, terminal, editor, text-editor

because of the fact that I am working a lot via SSH I am using an text editor named Minimum Profit ([link](https://triptico.com/software/mp.html)) its a terminal editor similar to vim, nano or emacs but it uses a lot of modern shortcuts like ctrl-s to save etc.

I am also programming a lot in c++ via terminal.
I have seen some ways so make emacs or vim enable autocomplete for some programming languages such as c++, perl, python etc.

Examples: [1. Emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete), [2. Vim](https://medium.com/vim-drops/css-autocompletion-on-vim-no-plugins-needed-e8df9ce079c7)

**Heres my question:**
Does anyone know a way to achieve this goal in the terminal version of the Minimum Profit Editor?
Other then changing its source code of course.

I am looking for plugins, scripts or fancy configurations to get it working.
My main goal it to have a c++ code completion for commands and object members.
(A linter would also be nice.)

Alternative if there is no easy way, I would also agree to use a similar editor as long as it features all the benefits of Minimum Profit, such as "normal" keyboard-shortcuts, mouse usage, being able to open multiple files at once, selection, copy/paste, git and build support, find and replace and syntax highlighting.

And no switching to emacs or vim is no option.

Comment: From the link in your question: "Creative use of tags: tags created by the external utility `ctags` are used to move instantaneously to functions or variables inside your current source tree. Tags are visually highlighted (underlined), and **symbol completion can be triggered to avoid typing your own function names over and over**." (emphasis mine) So it seems like it might already have it, if you give it a little help.

Comment: Its only a word completion. It only completes words that you have already used. I want a real code completion.